# html image maps and hover css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

Im working on a image map a previous dev created as part of a navigation. It will feature the UK map cut up into regions to navigate to them parts of the site. The previous dev used img maps, but image maps dont use css correctly as image maps are a legacy method.

Bellow is the code

```
<style type="text/css">

#map a {
    cursor: hand;
}

</style>

<div id="mapimage"><img src="ukmap.gif" USEMAP="#map" TYPE="image/png" TITLE="Join your local network" WIDTH=294 HEIGHT=486></div>

 <map id="map" name="map">


    <area shape="poly" id="northern" alt="Northern" title="Northern" coords="123,248,134,271,139,294,141,301,156,321,167,317,183,307,180,288,188,298,205,302,225,290,239,289,248,274,211,229,199,208,176,170,168,170,148,207,123,238" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="wales" shape="poly" alt="Wales" title="Wales" coords="100,302,92,332,110,338,111,355,64,374,88,400,133,398,154,404,164,384,161,372,144,364,145,344,154,321,143,302,103,293" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="westmidlands" shape="poly" alt="West Midlands" title="West Midlands" coords="181,368,195,360,206,351,189,326,182,305,149,321,142,358,147,369,163,376" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="eastmidlands" shape="poly" alt="East Midlands" title="East Midlands" coords="215,365,233,341,233,328,254,320,238,284,210,293,192,304,177,290,184,320,204,353,203,366" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="london" shape="poly" alt="London" title="London" coords="227,385,235,398,244,402,255,391,259,384,239,379,230,383" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="east" shape="poly" alt="East" title="East" coords="260,315,287,316,288,364,271,389,259,390,246,377,225,382,222,368,217,357,235,327" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="southwest" shape="poly" alt="South West" title="South West" coords="61,468,88,475,104,456,139,462,153,437,180,441,192,436,196,396,188,363,162,375,152,405,142,404,109,408,87,440" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="southeast" shape="poly" alt="South East" title="South East" coords="209,445,224,429,259,429,284,409,276,386,254,391,241,405,226,388,215,363,194,369,199,401,192,436" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="northernireland" shape="poly" alt="Northern Ireland" title="Northern Ireland" coords="46,270,56,267,81,244,58,215,33,203,1,237,0,252,9,268" href="#" target="" />

</map>
```

We need each of the areas to change colour on hover. would it be best to re write this using  div and ul/li with absolute positioning. Or is it possible to change the ukmap.gif with jquery/javascript on mouse over? as then i could have the same image with different areas blocked colour and change the image to mimic a css:hover, i dont want to undermine previous peoples work while at same time not wasting time rewriting it if a simple jquery hack can select these

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#map a {
    cursor: hand;
}

</style>
<script src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <script>
$('#mapimage').mapster(
    { 
        fillColor: 'ff0000'
    });​
</script>

<div>
    <img id="mapimage" src="images/map-complete.gif" USEMAP="#map" TYPE="image/png" TITLE="Join your local network" WIDTH=294 HEIGHT=486></div>

 <map id="map" name="map">


    <area shape="poly" id="northern" alt="Northern" title="Northern" coords="123,248,134,271,139,294,141,301,156,321,167,317,183,307,180,288,188,298,205,302,225,290,239,289,248,274,211,229,199,208,176,170,168,170,148,207,123,238" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="wales" shape="poly" alt="Wales" title="Wales" coords="100,302,92,332,110,338,111,355,64,374,88,400,133,398,154,404,164,384,161,372,144,364,145,344,154,321,143,302,103,293" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="westmidlands" shape="poly" alt="West Midlands" title="West Midlands" coords="181,368,195,360,206,351,189,326,182,305,149,321,142,358,147,369,163,376" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="eastmidlands" shape="poly" alt="East Midlands" title="East Midlands" coords="215,365,233,341,233,328,254,320,238,284,210,293,192,304,177,290,184,320,204,353,203,366" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="london" shape="poly" alt="London" title="London" coords="227,385,235,398,244,402,255,391,259,384,239,379,230,383" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="east" shape="poly" alt="East" title="East" coords="260,315,287,316,288,364,271,389,259,390,246,377,225,382,222,368,217,357,235,327" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="southwest" shape="poly" alt="South West" title="South West" coords="61,468,88,475,104,456,139,462,153,437,180,441,192,436,196,396,188,363,162,375,152,405,142,404,109,408,87,440" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="southeast" shape="poly" alt="South East" title="South East" coords="209,445,224,429,259,429,284,409,276,386,254,391,241,405,226,388,215,363,194,369,199,401,192,436" href="#" target="" />

    <area id="northernireland" shape="poly" alt="Northern Ireland" title="Northern Ireland" coords="46,270,56,267,81,244,58,215,33,203,1,237,0,252,9,268" href="#" target="" />

</map>
​
```

​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to restart everything you could do the following:
Add the hover code to each area, and change the source of the image.

```
$('#southeast').hover(
        function() {
            $('#mapimage img').attr('src', 'http://www.groupswelcome.co.uk/maps/uk_map.gif');
        },
        function() {
            $('#mapimage img').attr('src', 'http://www.alert24uk.com/ESW/Images/uk-map.gif');
        }
    );
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEXfA/) of this method (rollover southeast at the bottom right)... Images do not correspond to the mapping of course.

By doing this, you will see a blank image temporary... until the image loads.

There are ways to prevent this, like using a spritesheet instead. If interested, I can work up an example for you.

This is an easy way. There are other options.
HTML5 canvas if your website is for recent browsers.

Answer (score 6):

"image maps are a legacy method" -- untrue. HTML image maps are fully supported by the [HTML 5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/image-maps.html).

CSS simply doesn't apply to imagemaps.

Try [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster), a jquery plugin designed exactly for this purpose.

Here's a basic usage (same problem as the other answer - the areas don't match right, I couldn't easily find an accurate imagemap of the UK and don't have your source image that your areas match). But you get the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/VcGXL/

```
// basic implementation of hotspots with ImageMapster

$('#mapimage').mapster(
{ 
    fillColor: 'ff0000'
});
```

Comment: im having trouble implementing your method i supplied my working copy above

Comment: `#mapimage` is an id selector. In your HTML, that is on the div, not the image. I changed it to the image in the example. You need to target the image.

Comment: in the second example the #mapimage is on the image not the div, i took your code and put it together

    <script>
    $('#mapimage').mapster(
    { 
        fillColor: 'ff0000'
    });​
    </script>
 <div>
    <img id="mapimage"

Comment: Are you referencing the imagemapster script? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes referrencing imagemaster script and its in he rgiht directorys ect

here is the head of the doc

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#map a {
    cursor: hand;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapster/dist/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
<script>
$('#mapimage').mapster({
    fillColor: 'ff0000'
});​
</script>

error in browser console shows

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL > line 15

Comment: Just the closing syntax of the selector view it on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/kj59uTYw

If you were kind enough to put a working demo on pastebin id be forever gratefull

Comment: jsfiddle is a lot more useful than pastebin since you can actually run the code. It's impossible to say what isn't working from a cut and paste. Here's another fiddle with the code inline in script tags: http://jsfiddle.net/xQGBw/  The only thing I can think is some hidden unicode character? That error is a basic parsing error.

Comment: .. by the way DO NOT link to a script on github (like I did in that last fiddle) for any production use, it will only work in chrome & firefox.

Comment: thanks for the support i decided to go with the first idea, as your implementation only colours the sections between the coords, we didnt trace the timage exactly so you could see the overlap between the colour fill and the image. but your inline example helped me to structure the implementation thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

In fact the default display for area in none so you have to style it to **display:block** first, so put this CSS rule to change the cursor over the maps areas:

```
area{
    display:block;
    cursor:hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to jump on this question late in the game but I have an answer for irregular (non-rectangular) shapes. I solved it using SVGs to generate masks of where I want to have the event attached.

The idea is to attach events to inlined SVGs, super cheap and even user friendly because there are plenty of programs for generating SVGs. The SVG can have a layer of the image as a background.

http://jcrogel.com/code/2015/03/18/mapping-images-using-javascript-events/